# Schema issue with Kafka schema registry

Tags: avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I know I come to you with any news, but I'm stuck solving an issue that probably is my fault, indeed I can't realize what's the solution.
I'm using a standalone installation of the Confluent platform (4.0.0 open source version) in order to demonstrate how to adopt the platform for a specific use case.
Trying to demonstrate the value of using the schema registry I'm facing the following issue posting a new schema with Postman.

The request is:

```
http://host:8081/subjects/test/versions  
, method POST
, Header: Accept:application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json, application/vnd.schemaregistry+json, application/json
Content-Type:application/json
, Body: 
    {"schema":"{{\"namespace\":\"com.testlab\",\"name\":\"test\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"resourcepath\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"resource\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}}" }
```

The response is: {"error_code":42201,"message":"Input schema is an invalid Avro schema"}

Looking at docs and after googling a lot I'm without options.
Any suggestion ?
Thanks for your time
R.

Comment: Found the issue, removed elements regarding an "enum" type the schema's registration has been ok (maybe in the docs there's something about).
Apologies for the wrong request body in the question (anyway that request had same issue, but I can't say why).
HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra `{}` around the schema field.

One way to test this is with `jq`

Before

```
$ echo '{"schema":"{{\"namespace\":\"com.testlab\",\"name\":\"test\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"resourcepath\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"resource\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}}" }' | jq '.schema|fromjson'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Objects must consist of key:value pairs at line 1, column 146 (while parsing '{{"namespace":"com.testlab","name":"test","type":"record","fields":[{"name":"resourcepath","type":"string"},{"name":"resource","type":"string"}]}}')
```

After

```
$ echo '{"schema":"{\"namespace\":\"com.testlab\",\"name\":\"test\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"resourcepath\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"resource\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}" }' | jq  '.schema|fromjson'
{
  "namespace": "com.testlab",
  "name": "test",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "resourcepath",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "resource",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

See [my comment here](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/789#issuecomment-385064491) about importing AVSC files so that you don't need to type out the JSON on the CLI